# SQL - separate string into different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to separate strings into different columns which are separated by commas. I tried all the article that is on stackoverflow but not successful.

Example:

```
Column1
mouse,monitor,keyboard
cable,mouse
headset,desk,cable,monitor,usb,charger
```

Expected results:

```
Column1  |Column2  |Column3  |Column4  |Column5  |Column6 
mouse    |monitor  |keyboard | NULL    | NULL    | NULL
cable    |mouse    |NULL     | NULL    | NULL    | NULL
headset  |desk     |cable    | monitor | usb     | charger
```

Please note that the strings under *Column1* can be as many as 10 strings and the strings are different every week so they are undefined.

This is one of the code I tried:

```
Declare #TblName (id int, Column1 varchar(max))

Insert into #TblName 

Select A.Column1
      ,B.*
 From  #TblNameK A
 Cross Apply (
        Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
              ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
              ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
              ,Pos4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
              ,Pos5 = xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')
              ,Pos6 = xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')
              ,Pos7 = xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')
              ,Pos8 = xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')
              ,Pos9 = xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')
         From (Select Cast('<x>' + Replace(A.Column1,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML) as xDim) A
       ) B
```

Comment: So you have 1 column with store data like that? and not knowing how many will be that string to separate into column? i think you are in trouble..

Comment: You might need dynamic SQL to handle this.  Do you need to preserve the word order in the CSV when converting to columns?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i think i see your rep 201k..

Comment: @dwir182 yes, i have a column that store data like that. It's a column that stores the "search keywords" of our customers.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - after splitting the strings, I will have to "Group By" them.

Comment: @Jonathan you want to split them into columns then Group By them ? how come? isn't faster if you just put them into one column and then select distinct values, which will give you unique values ? a more explanation on why you need to do that in which will help us to understand the best approach for your case

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns

Comment: @iSR5 the reason for that is i need to the a "count" each strings.

Comment: @FaranSaleem Yes i did, but that's only if you know how many strings there would be in a row. How about if it's indefinite?

Comment: For an unknown number of columns I agree with Tim, as far as I know you will have to use dynamic sql. If you have a max number of columns you can use the xml trick to get the columns you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XML method below :

```
DECLARE 
    @t TABLE (keywords VARCHAR(MAX) ) 


INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
('mouse,monitor,keyboard'),
('cable,mouse'),
('headset,desk,cable,monitor,usb,charger'), 
('M&M,Hot&Cold,sneakers')



SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY keywords DESC) ID 
,   keywords 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','VARCHAR(8000)'))) keywords
    FROM (
        SELECT CAST('<Root><Keyword>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(keywords,'&','&amp;') ,',','</Keyword><Keyword>') + '</Keyword></Root>' AS XML) keywords
        FROM @t
    ) D
    CROSS APPLY keywords.nodes('/Root/Keyword')m(n)
) C
```

This will put each keyword in a row. From there you can count the number of keywords and do further stuff on them (like getting the distinct values, pivot them ..etc).

Comment: I am getting " Msg 9411, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XML parsing: line 1, character 20, semicolon expected "

Comment: @Jonathan is your data has some  <,>, & characters  ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SQL Server 2016, you can use the built-in `string_split()` function:

```
declare @t table (Value varchar(max));

insert into @t (Value)
values
    ('mouse,monitor,keyboard'),
    ('cable,mouse'),
    ('headset,desk,cable,monitor,usb,charger')
;

select *
from @t t
    cross apply string_split(t.Value, ',') ss;
```

Having all the values in one column will be especially handy if you are actually going to get some aggregated statistics out of them.

Comment: under values, you've written the example strings given above, what if i don't know what are the strings? or the number of rows?

Comment: @Jonathan Just check code in this answer with your own data sets.

Comment: @Serg I am getting Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: @Jonathan What tool and how are you using to run this code?

Comment: @Serg oh i get it now. ran the code but getting " invalid  object name 'string_split' "

Comment: @Jonathan Could you please run the following code and provide its output here: `select @@version;`

Comment: @Serg Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU8) (KB4077064) - 13.0.4474.0 (X64)   Feb 24 2018 13:53:17   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182077/discussion-between-serg-and-jonathan).